# How do I reformat ruby code from the command line?

Tags: ruby, command-line, code-formatting

Given a source file with bad indentation, incorrect white space management, and so on. How do I reformat the code such a file and apply the Ruby's style guide (if present)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a task of your editor. In vim (configured for Ruby), just press `gg=G` xD

A Ruby script that does it is available at: http://www.arachnoid.com/ruby/rbeautify.rb.html

Comment: That was exactly the script I was looking for (thnx). Tried it, commit [15c34bf](https://github.com/tiesmaster/dotfiles/commit/15c34bf524fe8c6573d31282086371dcadf7c829) shows an example.

Comment: btw I suspect TextMate ships with built-in Ruby support, so that a plus. VIM will do it, but that needs adjustment. I wanted something that's available from the command line to prevent the editor minefield (for TextMate, you need a licence, for VIM you need plugins, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried it myself:

http://www.arachnoid.com/ruby/rubyBeautifier.html